# Cannot deploy public api on Cloud Run using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform now supports cloud run as documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloud_run_service.html),
and I'm trying the example code below.

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "tftest-cloudrun"
  location = "us-central1"
  provider = "google-beta"

  metadata {
    namespace = "my-project-name"
  }

  spec {
    containers {
      image = "gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"
    }
  }
}
```

Although it deploys the sample hello service with no error, when I access to the auto-generated URL, it returns 403(Forbidden) response.
Is it possible to create public cloud run api using terraform?

(When I'm creating the same service using GUI, GCP provides "Allow unauthenticated invocations" option under "Authentication" section, but there seems to be no equivalent option in terraform document...)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the deployment is only based on Knative serving spec. Cloud Run managed implements these specs but have its own internal behavior, like role check linked with IAM (not possible with Knative and a K8S cluster, this is replaced by Private/Public service). The namespace on Cloud Run managed is the projectId, a workaround to identify the project for example, not a real K8S namespace.

So, the latest news that I have from Google (I'm Cloud Run Alpha Tester) which tells they are working with Deployment Manager and Terraform for integrating Cloud Run in them. I don't have deadline, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it will be available someday :)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't quite understand it: Is there currently a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Today with Terraform, you have to deploy your service and explicitly add the iam policy biding for making your service public. You can't do all in the same terraform resource defintion.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the following code to your terraform script, which will make it publicly accessable

```
data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}
```

You can also find this [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloud_run_service.html)

Comment: A get a error, is │ Error: Error setting IAM policy for cloudrun service "v1/projects/projectId/locations/us-east4/services/service": googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/projectId/locations/us-east4/services/service' (or resource may not exist).

Comment: @MarconWillian Did you figure this out? I am very much stuck with this same error.

Comment: Figured this out- I needed to create a role for my service account that had the correct permissions